# Open Internet Explorer browser with POST parameters

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, post, xna, windows-phone

I would like to open a webpage in Internet Explorer using the `WebBrowserTask` but I would also like to pass a POST parameter(s) as well.

Is this possible using the `WebBrowserTask`?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is part of an XNA project. All I would like to do is to display a webpage and passing POST parameters with the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the WebClient object to accomplish this though it is much more obscure. Webclient is a wrapper around HTTPRequest. It is like HTTPRequest on easy mode. The trade off is that if you want to send post data then you need to be crafty about it. You can create new headers in WebClient and set their names to what you need. Then when you make the call it will send them out as post data. Sounds complicated but actually pretty easy and clean when implemented. WAY cleaner than HTTPRequest.

Answer (score 0):

`WebBrowserTask` can only navigate to a specific page and invoke GET request. You can simulate POST requests using the `HttpWebRequest`, but I doubt that will help you with what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with the `WebBrowserTask`, however it is possible using the `WebBrowser` control.

Specifically check out the [`Navigate` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626636%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) of `WebBrowser`.

This takes a `byte[]` with your POST data.

```
public void Navigate(
Uri uri,
byte[] postData,
string additionalHeaders)
```